# How can I create a database and USE statements in one script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exec

Consider the following script:

```
DECLARE @path varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @script varchar(MAX)
SET @path = (SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files where name = 'master');
SET @path = REPLACE(@path, 'master.mdf', '');
SELECT @path;

SET @script = 
'CREATE DATABASE test
 ON PRIMARY
 (NAME = test_primary,
  FILENAME = ''' + @path + 'test_primary.mdf'',
  SIZE = 10MB,
  FILEGROWTH = 10MB)';

exec(@script);

USE test
```

When I try to run it all at once I get an error:

```
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
Database 'test' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

If I first run exec and then separately run `USE` it all goes fine.

The question is, how can I work-around it, so that it'd be possible to run the whole script at once with no errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server compiles the code for one batch at a time. When your code is compiled the database does not exist.

Add a [batch separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) before `use test`.

```
DECLARE @path varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @script varchar(MAX)
SET @path = (SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files where name = 'master');
SET @path = REPLACE(@path, 'master.mdf', '');
SELECT @path;

SET @script = 
'CREATE DATABASE test
 ON PRIMARY
 (NAME = test_primary,
  FILENAME = ''' + @path + 'test_primary.mdf'',
  SIZE = 10MB,
  FILEGROWTH = 10MB)';

exec(@script);

GO

USE test
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are executing the statements from within one of the SQL Server query tools (e.g. enterprise manager, management studio or `sqlcmd`), then insert the statement `GO` prior to the `USE test` command.  This separates the commands into separate batches.  If you are executing the script through one of the programmatic clients, then you must execute the batches separately by splitting up the script.

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer, but for me it seems that Mikael Eriksson's answer is a bit more precise. +1 anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Souldn't USE be at the top of the script?

USE selects the correct database for you. Then run the script on that database

Comment: he's creating the `test` database, then trying to do something with it